# Getting WooCommerce customers and/or orders by emailaddress with REST API v3

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I have read through tons of related questions and answers, but I'm not getting my desired results.
Not sure if API v3 even handles these simple filters for customers and orders.

What I want to do is filter orders by email and/or zipcode so people can lookup their orders from our Apps.

```
/*
 * Get Customer
 * email@example.com
 */

$data = [
    'filter' => [
        'email' => '****@gmail.com',
        //'billing_phone' => '123156466'
        ]];
print_r($woocommerce->get('customers', $data));


/*
 * Get Orders
 * email@example.com
 */


$data = [
    'filter' => [
        //'fields' => 'id,status,email',
        'email'  => '****@gmail.com'
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->get('orders', $data));
```

Also tried to append a querystring, like:

```
$qs = http_build_query($data);
print_r($woocommerce->get('orders/?' . $qs));
```

Also tried without 'filter', so no nested arrray.

Am I trying to make things work that are not supported?

Comment: I think you need to grab the customer_id in woocommerce from the email address,  then filter orders by customer_id  (note) customer_id in some cases is different than user_id in wordpress

Comment: Agreed, that was my 2nd option, but that doesn't work either as per my sample code above. It returns an empty Array (email does exist).